association matrix, nominal-nominal scale, nominal-ratio scale
For ratio scale data it is relatively simple to create and visualize a correlation matrix e.g. as shown below. How can I do the same for a data frame that contains also nominal scale data? I would like to see associations (e.g. Cramer's Phi or others) for nominal-nominal, and nominal-ratio pairs and correlation for ratio-ratio pair variables. Something like the matrix the sweetviz Python package generates for an automatic exploratory data analysis.
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,15))         # Sample figsize in inches (width, heights)
hm = sns.heatmap(df[meta_data + summary_ravenscroft].corr(method='spearman'), vmin=-1, vmax=1, annot=True, ax=ax);

# Give a title to the heatmap. Pad defines the distance of the title from the top of the heatmap.
hm.set_title('Correlation Heatmap', fontdict={'fontsize':12}, pad=12);

